# Cleaning old data after inserting the new data into table

Tags: mysql, sql

First we start with empty table

**rows = 0**

Second we insert random rows let say 3400

**rows = 3400**

For the third time i count how many rows are in the table, then insert the new rows and after that delete rows <= from the count.

This logic only work for the first time. If that repeat the count will always be 3400 but the id will increase so it will not delete the rows

I cant use last inserted ID since the rows are random and I dont how many it will load.

// Update

```
"SELECT count(*) from table" - the total count so far
"INSERT INTO tab_videos_watched (id , name) values (id , name)" - this is random can     be 3400 or 5060 or 1200
"DELETE FROM table  WHERE idtable  <= $table_count"
```

Comment: Can you show your sql? Also, what does _"delete rows <= from the count"_ mean?

Comment: please post a SSCCE so we can see what you are doing

Comment: I think he's asking how does he use the old id's to rows that he just deleted? If so, AUTO_INCREMENT will not allow you to do that since it auto assigns your id's already. This is done to increase the speed of your INSERT queries so it doesn't have to calculate the next available ID, it just has it off hand.

Comment: From the information you've given, it ought to be sufficient to first delete everything in the table and *then* perform your inserts.  However, if you must insert first and delete later, why not keep track of the round in which records were inserted in a new column: then you can simply `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE round = 3` or whatever.

Comment: @MarianPetrov: By "round", I meant a round of insertions (since it appears that is how you are determining the data you wish to delete)?

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is auto incremented, then you should use like:

```
select max(id) from my_table;
```

Read this `maxId` into a variable and then use when issued a `delete` query like:

```
delete from my_table where id <= ?;
```

Replace query parameter with the last found `maxId` value.

Alternatively you can define a column `last_inserted` as `datetime` type.
Before next insertions, select it into a local variable.

```
select max(last_inserted) as 'last_inserted' from my_table;
```

And after insertions are made, use the `last_inserted` to delete records.

```
delete from my_table where last_inserted <= ?;
```

Replace query parameter with the last found `last_inserted` value.

Comment: True, but at least the table should have provisioned a last insert date time field.